# ObservableCollection dependency Property is not updating on Usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

Here the observable collection is getting updated but it doesn't reflect on the UI.

XAML

```
<ComboBox Name="ProductsCombo" Width="200" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Products}"
                  DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                  SelectedValue="ID"
                  SelectionChanged="OnProductSelected"/>

<Button Click="AddNewProduct" Content="Add New Product" Width="105" Margin="5"/>
```

In my code behind

```
public partial class ProductsAdd : UserControl
{
    SampleContext DbContext = new MedicalShopContext();


    public ProductsAdd()
    {
        DataContext = this;

        InitializeComponent();

        Products = new ObservableCollection<Product>(DbContext.Products);
        ProductsCombo.SelectedItem = Products[0];
    }

    public void AddNewProduct(string ProductName, string ProductDescription)
    {
        NewProduct = new Product()
        {
            Name = ProductName,
            Description = ProductDescription
        };

        DbContext.Products.Add(NewProduct);
        DbContext.SaveChanges();
        Products.Add(NewProduct);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Product> Products
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<Product>)GetValue(ProductsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ProductsProperty, value); }
    }



public static readonly DependencyProperty ProductsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Products",
            typeof(ObservableCollection<Product>),
            typeof(ProductsAdd),
            new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public Product NewProduct
    {
        get { return (Product)GetValue(NewProductProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NewProductProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for NewProduct.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty NewProductProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("NewProduct",
        typeof(Product),
        typeof(ProductsAdd),
        new PropertyMetadata(null));

    private void AddNewProduct(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NewProductInput productInputWindow = new NewProductInput();
        productInputWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

The above binding works if we call from same UI. but it is not updating when calling from other window

Below is the code for new window whcih is shown on button click

```
public partial class NewProductInput : Window
{

    public NewProductInput()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Close(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ProductsAdd productsAddWindow = new ProductsAdd();
        productsAddWindow.AddNewProduct(txtProductName.Text, txtProductDescription.Text);
        this.Close();            
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean that you want Products collection to update when NewProductInput window is closed?

Comment: yes Didier collection shows recently added element but in UI it is not getting updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in your UI control the Products collection is populated only once and then never get updated.

```
Products = new ObservableCollection<Product>(DbContext.Products);
```

When you write this it means that the Observable collection will contain the same items from DbContext.Products but it wont be updated if DbContext.Products changes. And that's what happens when a window closes. I suggest you to handle the Closed event and to recreate the collection again in the same way.

```
private void AddNewProduct(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    NewProductInput productInputWindow = new NewProductInput();
    productInputWindow.Show();
    productInputWindow.Closed += OnProductInputWindowClosed;
}

private void OnProductInputWindowClosed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    (sender as Window).Closed -= OnProductInputWindowClosed;
    Products = new ObservableCollection<Product>(DbContext.Products);
}
```

It's the easiest solution however not the best one as this will force to recreate all of the UI Items in the ComboBox.

Comment: Can you please suggest me how to handle this scenarios with a effective solution?? Any design pattern?

Comment: Ideally you can run through the existing collection and the newlly retrieved and then add remove items in the existing collection to match the new one. In this way only the newlly added/removed items will be changed visually in WPF.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have 2 different instances of ProductsAdd user control. The following line creates a new instance of products add, an instance that has nothing to 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Products}"

```
ProductsAdd productsAddWindow = new ProductsAdd();
```

Comment: Hi MichaelLo how can solve this problem? What ever you said is true if I write same code in the usercontrol it works but if I call from other window I need to restsrt the app again for updated collection

Comment: You need to populate Products in some way, but that depends of you app structure. You might consider a service that holds one copy of it and is being injected into both controls.